# How to separate alt and meta keys in emacs

Tags: emacs

I would like to map a <kbd>PgUp</kbd> key on my keyboard to <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier to produce `A-` key sequence in Emacs, so that I can map it to a whole new set of key bindings.

I was looking at my keyboard mappigs and currently my left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key works as both <kbd>Meta_L</kbd>
and <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> modifier. This is the relevant output of `xmodmap -pke`:

```
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
```

I'm not sure how to tell emacs to treat <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd> totally separately,

I have looked at the `x-alt-keysym` and it is `nil`

```
Which keys Emacs uses for the alt modifier.
This should be one of the symbols `alt', `hyper', `meta', `super'.
For example, `alt' means use the Alt_L and Alt_R keysyms.  The default
is nil, which is the same as `alt'.
```

The same is for `x-meta-keysym` and it is also `nil`:

```
Which keys Emacs uses for the meta modifier.
This should be one of the symbols `alt', `hyper', `meta', `super'.
For example, `meta' means use the Meta_L and Meta_R keysyms.  The 
default is nil, which is the same as `meta'.
```

From this it implies that `Alt_L` should fire `alt`, however it always fires `meta` as it is indicated by the `M-` in the minibar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs does distinguish between <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>.

In your case your current combined <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Meta</kbd> either appears as an <kbd>Alt</kbd> or as a <kbd>Meta</kbd>.  If there's no <kbd>Meta</kbd> key, Emacs automatically treats the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as a <kbd>Meta</kbd>. So in the end your combined <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Meta</kbd> will behave as a <kbd>Meta</kbd> in Emacs.

But if you set your modifiers with separate keys for <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>, Emacs will readily distinguish them.

Comment: Why not just remap it to `hyper` instead?

Comment: @Dan: what do you mean by "it"?  For the record, my answer just explains that there's no need to do anything on Emacs's side; just change your xmodmap config and Emacs will obey it.

Comment: Sorry, meant for original poster: if you want another modifier, you could map `PgUp` to `hyper` instead.

Comment: Yes, this works, just remap that Alt_L is alywas Meta_L and Alt_R is alywas Alt_R and it works

p.s.
I have Hyper mapped as well, but wanted so see if it is posslbe to have all of them at the same time :)