# Remap Win, Ctrl and Alt keys on Linux

Tags: linux, emacs, configuration, keyboard

### The question:

How can I remap (swap) modifier keys system-wide on Linux?

### Explanation:

I want to install Debian Jessie on my PC to use it with Emacs.  I have a MacBook with Emacs and use it primarily.  Here is how keys are arranged on laptop:

<kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>spacebar</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd>

<kbd>fn</kbd> is unused in my Emacs workflow, other keys configured as listed below:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> acts as `Hyper`
- <kbd>alt</kbd> acts as `Meta`
- <kbd>cmd</kbd> acts as `Control`

These configuration eases for me Emacs experience (big thumb hits `Control` <kbd>cmd</kbd> key) and I got used to this kind of key bindings.

*by default <kbd>alt</kbd> is used as `Meta`, while <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is used as `Control`, the keys are swapped and big thumb lays on `Meta`*

I want to configure my keys on Linux same way, here is what I have on my PC's keyboard:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>win</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>spacebar</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>win</kbd> <kbd>menu</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>

So, to correspond to my laptop keys, I want <kbd>win</kbd> keys to be mapped to `Alt` modifier, and <kbd>alt</kbd> keys to be mapped to `Control` modifier.  In this case <kbd>ctrl</kbd> could be used as `Super` modifier, while <kbd>menu</kbd> could be kept untouched.

Is it possible to make such configuration system-wide on Linux (Debian)?

---

Finally, I have managed to achieve my goal with following configuration:

```
!file ~/.Xmodmap

clear control
clear mod1
clear mod4


keycode 37  = Super_L     
! left  Ctrl becomes Super
keycode 64  = Control_L
! left  Alt  becomes Control 
keycode 133 = Alt_L Meta_L
! left  Win  becomes Alt
keycode 108 = Control_R
! right Alt  becomes Control 
keycode 134 = Alt_R Meta_R
! right Win  becomes Alt
keycode 105 = Super_R
! right Ctrl becomes Super


add control = Control_L Control_R
add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
add mod4 = Super_L Super_R
```

Also, here is [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93624/how-do-i-swap-left-ctrl-with-left-alt-on-my-keyboard) with quite helpful and simple guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`xmodmap`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) is the place to start, keeping in mind that X knows nothing about `Hyper` or `Meta`, so you have to investigate to see which numbered modifier (mod4, mod5, etc), emacs uses for these modifiers.

Here are a few useful links:

- [XModMap](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/XModMap)
- [How to separate alt and meta keys in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463415/how-to-separate-alt-and-meta-keys-in-emacs)
- [MetaKeyProblems](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MetaKeyProblems)
- [Emacs does not use swapped alt&win after xmodmap runs? (GUI emacs)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/emacs-does-not-use-swapped-altwin-after-xmodmap-runs-gui-emacs)

Comment: I'm still have no idea how can I swap keys system-wide, is it even possible to make this kind of configuration happen at boot time?

Comment: At boot time, there's no X running, and as [@Hannes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/495681/hannes) pointed out, none of the X settings would apply.  However, most emacs users rely upon the GUI, and (unlike [setxkbmap](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.html)) it is possible to get useful information from the manual page for xmodmap -- thus the answer which I provided.

Comment: what I want is not configure Emacs keys, but remap `win` key to `alt` and `ctrl` for all system apps and etc.

Comment: ...and xmodmap is the place to *start* for that goal, because it does exactly that.

Answer (score 6):

Additionally to and possibly easier than using `xmodmap` might be to check in the keyboard layout options given by `setxkbmap`. These options implement common `xmodmap` changes, so they might well contain what you want.

For example, I like `-option ctrl:nocaps` which adds me another `control` where the `caps lock` was. Consider the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` for a list of the standard options.

However, neither `xmodmap` nor `setxkbmap` include keyboard settings for the text-only `tty` terminals (non-X).

Answer (score 2):

xmodmap/setxkbmap methods are great until you have 2nd keyboard that doesn't require any remapping. For example laptop and external keyboard.

I found [swapping via udev hwdb](https://gist.github.com/rbreaves/9a0a2bb8b0d6c2142acbbfa78c382262) the best because it changes only specific keyboard. For example in case of Framework laptop and Pop!OS (also should work on most Debian derivatives) to swap alt and win keys it is required to create a file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/99-fw-meta-alt.hwdb`:

```
evdev:input:b0011v0001p0001*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_38=leftmeta
  KEYBOARD_KEY_db=leftalt
```

and then run

```
sudo systemd-hwdb update
sudo udevadm trigger
```

This makes alt-win swap only on internal laptop's keyboard only without remapping all other keyboards I connect to my laptop.

Comment: This sounds like the solution I've been looking for, I'll test it out. Does this change affect also non-desktop environments? for example if I open a tty or try to send a "REISUB"?

Answer (score 1):

**Full Disclosure**

I am the author of Kinto.

You may find Kinto to be useful. It's a project I recently created, after a few years of tackling this problem a few different ways and I just now feel like it's solid enough to share.

The Kinto installer simply uses python to do the initial install, after that it's just a systemd service, bash, xprop, setxkbmap and xkbcomp. As far as I am concerned it is the fastest and most native solution to this problem that you are going to find.

Also Xmodmap is defunct, it will not work going forward with Wayland.

https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto

https://medium.com/@benreaves/kinto-a-mac-inspired-keyboard-mapping-for-linux-58f731817c0

Here's a Gist as well, if you just want to see what is at the heart of it all, it will not alternate your keymap when needed though. The Gist also does not include custom xkb keymap files that setup macOS style cursors/word-wise manipulations that use Cmd and the arrow keys.

https://gist.github.com/rbreaves/f4cf8a991eaeea893999964f5e83eebb

gist content

```
# permanent apple keyboard keyswap
echo "options hid_apple swap_opt_cmd=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
update-initramfs -u -k all

# Temporary & instant apple keyboard keyswap
echo '1' | sudo tee -a /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/swap_opt_cmd

# Windows and Mac keyboards - GUI (Physical Alt is Ctrl, Physical Super is Alt, Physical Ctrl is Super)
setxkbmap -option;setxkbmap -option altwin:ctrl_alt_win

# Windows and Mac keyboards - Terminal Apps (Physical Alt is Super, Physical Super is Alt, Physical Ctrl is Ctrl)
setxkbmap -option;setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_alt_win

#
# If you want a systemd service and bash script to help toggle between
# GUI and Terminal applications then look at project Kinto.
# https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto
#
# Note: The above may not work for Chromebooks running Linux, please look
# at project Kinto for that.
#
# If anyone would like to contribute to the project then please do!
#
```

Comment: Notifying @Makyen of disclosure.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using KDE you can assign the command key to Alt using the following method, but it will render the option key useless.

meaning you'll end up with two alts in command and option keys, but still better than the default

you can go to settings > keyboard > advanced tab > alt/win key behavior > check Alt is mapped to Win and the usual Alt > OK